# Python interpreter misbehaving

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythoninterpreter

I installed python in my system and no error occurred, I also configured it for vs code but anything I open VsCode, I get prompted with the python interpreter telling me to repair or uninstall and it opens up a lot on my taskbar multiple times
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please read this [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

From within VS Code, select a Python 3 interpreter by opening the **Command Palette** (Ctrl+Shift+P), start typing the `Python: Select Interpreter` command to search, then select the command. You can also use the Select Python Environment option on the Status Bar if available (it may already show a selected interpreter, too):

[image: No interpreter selected]